# Detecting change is column value and plotting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

My Data in column 2 (shown with header name **N** here) includes number of cycles which are repetitive from 0 to 15 or from 0 to 7 etc.  Column number 3 **CN** is calculated by `CN = np.cumsum(np.abs(np.diff(N)))`

I want to get a slice from the data according to **CN** values. From value of 1 to 14 and from value of 29-36 and so on and then plot for **N** and **CN** .
The problem I am facing is that I have to check **CN** value manually for slices before plotting. I want an program which can slice the data whenever **CN** value has sudden jumping and then plot

---

```
+-------+-----+----+-------+
| index |  N  | CN | Vdiff |
+-------+-----+----+-------+
|   524 |   2 |  1 |   0.0 |
|   525 | 2   |  1 |   0.0 |
|   526 |   2 |  1 |   0.0 |
|     . |     |    |       |
|     . |     |    |       |
|  5900 |  15 | 14 |   0.0 |
|  5901 |  15 | 29 |   0.1 |
|  5902 |   0 | 29 |   0.0 |
|     . |     |    |       |
|     . |     |    |       |
| 33001 |   7 | 36 |   0.0 |
| 33002 |   7 | 36 |   0.0 |
| 33003 |   7 | 43 |   0.1 |
| 33004 |   0 | 43 |   0.0 |
+-------+-----+----+-------+
```

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
flt1 = (data['CN'] > 0) & (data['CN'] <= 14) 
Amp1 = data.loc[flt1] 

flt2 = (data['CN'] > 30) & (data['CN'] <= 36)   
Amp2 = data.loc[flt2]  

Amp1.plot(x='N',y='CN',kind='line')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to produce plots between the jumps in CN. Then, the following piece of code should do it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

jump_size = 5 # the size of what you consider to be a "jump" in CN
idx = list( data.index[data.CN.diff() >= jump_size] + 1 ) # find jump indexes

# if necessary, add the first index and the last index of your data
if idx[0] != 0: idx = [0]+idx
if idx[-1] != data.shape[0]: idx = idx+[None]

# produce plots between the jumps in CN
for imin,imax in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:]):
    data.iloc[imin:imax].plot(x='N',y='CN',kind='line')
    plt.show()
```

Let me know if this produces the results you want.

**EDIT:** As requested in the comments, here is the same `for` loop as before, but with matplotlib plotting instead of plotting directly from pandas dataframe:

```
for imin,imax in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:]):
    data_slice = data.iloc[imin:imax]
    plt.plot(data_slice.N, data_slice.CN)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: The first code gives the good plots but second keeps on plotting. I think there is some problem in the loop. You got the idea right when N==0 starts CN changes from the previous row due to cumsum. 1 thing I would like is to use matplotlib to plot instead of plotting from pandas dataframe if you can add this it'd be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: and can you please tell why jump_size=5?

Comment: @شاهنواز . Ah yes you are right, the second loop only works if there are no repeating consecutive zeros in N. I will edit that "alternative way" answer out since it doesn't work in general.

Comment: @شاهنواز . There is no real reason why jump_size=5. You could also set jump_size=2. I think it should work in your case for any value of jump_size between 2 and 7.